# Time complexity for a divide and conquer algorithm that creates two uneven subproblems.

Tags: time-complexity, divide-and-conquer

I am working with a very specific divide and conquer algorithm that always divides a problem with n elements into two subproblems with n/2 - 1 and n/2 + 1 elements.

I am pretty sure the time complexity remains O(n log n), but I wonder how could I formally prove it.

Answer (score 0):

Take the "useful work done" at each recursion level to be some function `f(n)`:

[image]

Let's observe what happens when we repeatedly substitute this back into itself.

---

1. `T(n)` terms:

[image]
Spot the pattern?

At recursion depth `m`:

- There are [image] recursive calls to `T`
- The first term in each parameter for `T` is [image]
- The second term ranges from [image] to [image], in steps of [image]

Thus the sum of all `T`-terms at each level is given by:

[image]

---

2. `f(n)` terms:

[image]

Look familiar?

The `f(n)` terms are *exactly one recursion level **behind*** the `T(n)` terms. Therefore adapting the previous expression, we arrive at the following sum:

[image]

However note that we only start with *one* `f`-term, so this sum has an invalid edge case. However this is simple to rectify - the special-case result for `m = 1` is simply `f(n)`.

---

Combining the above, and summing the `f` terms for *each recursion level*, we arrive at the (almost) final expression for `T(n)`:

[image]

---

We next need to find when the first summation for `T`-terms terminates. Let's assume that is when `n ≤ c`.

The **last** call to terminate intuitively has the largest argument, i.e the call to:

[image]

Therefore the final expression is given by:

[image]

---

Back to the original problem, what is `f(n)`?

You haven't stated what this is, so I can only assume that the amount of work done per call is `ϴ(n)` (proportional to the array length). Thus:

> [image]
>
> Your hypothesis was correct.

---

Note that even if we had something more general like

[image]

Where `a` is some constant not equal to 1, we would *still* have `ϴ(n log n)` as the result, since the [image] terms in the above equation cancel out:

[image]

Comment: I finally got it. Thanks!  What if the amount of work done is log(n), instead of n (like searching in an ordered array)? I suppose the complexity falls to O(n).  How to adjust the final part of the proof ?

Comment: Replace `f(n)` with `log(n)`. However the solution becomes non-trivial, so we may need to make some approximations to arrive at a final answer.